# Show only the LAST few characters of a cell when data is to wide in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a sheet that contains a column of xpath expressions (these resemble file paths.)  For the most part the first 50 or so characters are always the same.  This causes the data to be unhelpful when the column width is made too narrow.  **Is there a way to get Excel to only show the latter portion of the record when the column is shrunk down.**

The actual data looks like this but is quite a bit wider: (and can't change)

```
/some/path/to/my/stuff/name
/some/path/to/my/stuff/address
/some/path/to/my/stuff/city
/some/path/to/my/stuff/state
/some/path/to/my/stuff/zip
```

When the column is narrow I see this:

```
/some/path/to
/some/path/to
/some/path/to
/some/path/to
/some/path/to
```

I want to see something like this:

```
...ff/name
...ff/address
...ff/city
...ff/state
...ff/zip
```

Comment: Setting the cell to justify to the right?

Comment: I'm interested in solving this same problem. I have actual file paths. Since many of the file paths begin the same way ( or end the same way ) It may make since to break up the text. For example if everything you have starts `/some/path/to/my/stuff/` keep that separate from `name`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip` Then just concatenate later when you actually use that data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The start of the text is displayed by default because the text is aligned to the left (start) of each column.  Set the column's alignment to Align Text Right and it will show the ending of each cell when the data is cut off.